# Azure function code in python how to print out dataframe for https-request

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I would like to print dataframe on azure function with func.HttpRequest. The function works okey but no output. How can I update my code to ouput dataframe? Please help.
Thank you

```py
config = {
    'host':' ',
    'database' : '',
    'user' : '',
    'password' : '',
    'port':'',
    'client_flags': [mysql.connector.ClientFlag.SSL],
    'ssl_ca': 'DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem'
}

def select_table():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    myresult=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM events")
    return myresult

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    data=select_table()
    print(data)
    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below **python** code, I can able to print dataframe on azure function with func.HttpRequest.

```py
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func

config = {
  'host':'<servername>.mysql.database.azure.com',
  'database' : '<databasename>' ,
  'user' : '<username>', 
  'password' : '<password>' ,
  'port':'3306',
  'client_flags': [mysql.connector.ClientFlag.SSL],
  'ssl_ca': '<path-to-SSL-cert>/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem'
}

def select_table():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM kamalisql.empdetails")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=[i[0] for i in cursor.description])
    return df.to_json()

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    data = select_table()
    return func.HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
```

It run successfully,

**Output:**

[image]

I got the output at browser with the above URL,

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer but the date format changes to   "Date": {
    "0": 1683590400000,
    "1": 1683590400000,
    "2": 1683590400000,
    "3": 1683590400000,
    "4": 1683590400000
  },
How can I avoid that? Thank you